# How can an iOS app programmatically control cellular data

Tags: ios, objective-c, wifi, cellular-network

is it possible to make a widget so that I can turn off cellular data in the Today Widgets?
I'm trying to make an app which can control the cellular data for all the device, like a cellular data switch

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible, unless you're talking about a jailbroken device. Apple does not let 3rd party apps control the global functioning of the device.